# T-SQL usage of Variable with "IN" clause

Tags: t-sql

In our company, the following logic is used in most of SP's. I couldn't understand how a variable is used with the IN Clause like the following query.
Can anyone explain this?

```
WHERE ( ( @EMP_ID ) in ( select distinct(EMP_ID) 
from Table2(nolock) 
where SID = T1.SID and status='A' and client_id=T1.Client_Id ) ) 
order by EMP_ID
```

Comment: Can you paste a syntactically valid query? `WHERE ... FROM ... WHERE` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is simply replaced in the query.  If it helps, break down the query and think of it if you put in a number for the variable (for example, 45) and a list in place of the inner query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 45 IN (42, 46, 47, 90, 45)
```

This will return rows that contain an employee ID of 45.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes, someone can explain it.  Probably not me.

The `SELECT` gets a collection of `EMP_ID` values from `Table2`.  The first `WHERE` clause then checks if the value of variable `@EMP_ID` is **in** the set of selected values.  If so, the `WHERE` clause causes its parent statement to process the row.

The `SELECT` is a correlated subquery.  It uses a couple of values, `SID` and `Client_Id`, from a table (aliased as) `T1`.  (Said table is not included in your code snippet.)  For each row processed from `T1` the correlated subquery is evaluated.

Comment: Hi Garrett & HABO, Thankyou very much for the information given. I got the point.